# Add allow-modals to the sandbox of Stack Snippets, snippets are broken in Chrome 46+

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets, google-chrome

Chrome [blocks modal dialogs such as `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt` in sandboxed iframes unless `allow-modals` is set](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/mXX0AO6Lioo). This behavior became the default [as of Chrome 46 and Opera 34](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4747009953103872).

This breaks Stack snippets that make use of modal dialogs. Fortunately, there is a way to re-enable them, by appending `allow-modals` to the sandbox whitelist, so let's add it, **because Stack snippets using modal dialogs are broken since Chrome 46**.

Comment: _"or Stack snippets using modal dialogs will cease to work within two weeks."_  If we only had 6 to 8 weeks...

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308672/alerts-no-longer-work-in-stackoverflow-snippets-in-chrome-46

Comment: I just discovered this bug while viewing [an old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916874/can-you-tell-if-one-element-is-touching-another-using-javascript/29959520#29959520) that uses `alert()`. As a workaround, I added redundant `console.log()` statements and a note in the HTML markup informing the user that they may need to open their console to see the messages. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just pushed a fix for this. Sorry about the delay here - guess nobody noticed the report until recently.

The fix will be live in the next build (2015.12.1.3045 on SO, 2015.12.1.3939 here).

Comment: Thank you! I was almost starting to get used to `document.write()` _*Shudder*_

Comment: Please allow forms too. Several questions need onsubmit and it is blocked

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for a proper fix from SE, here's a quick JS hack to fix this:

```js
$(document).on( 'submit', 'form[action="//stacksnippets.net/js"]', function () {
    if ( ! /^[\-0-9A-Za-z]+$/.test( this.target ) ) return;  // safety check
    var iframe = $( 'iframe[name="' + this.target + '"][sandbox=allow-scripts]' );
    iframe.attr( 'sandbox', 'allow-scripts allow-modals' );
} );
```

This hack works by injecting the `allow-modals` sandbox flag into the `iframe` tag just before the snippet is executed.  I've tested this on Chrome 46 / Linux, and it successfully re-enables alerts in snippets.  It should have no visible effect on browsers that don't support `allow-modals` yet.

I've included this fix in version 1.40 of my [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script.  To install it, first get the [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) extension from Chrome Web Store, and then visit [this link to install SOUP](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/master/SOUP.user.js).

Comment: There are more ways to generate the iframe. You could take a look at the source code to see what's necessary: https://meta.dev.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/snippet-javascript.en.js?v=e21fcb06cc53. One way to get it to work is to patch `$.fn.init`, and replace `sandbox="allow-scripts"` with `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-modals"` if `$.fn.init` is called with exactly one argument (a string). If done properly, it will be more robust than your current snippet.

Comment: @RobW: I though about that first, but patching `$.fn.init` turns out to be [kind of tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536788/override-jquery-functions/4567878#comment54440042_4567878). But it turns out it doesn't matter how or when the iframe is *created*, since I only need to fix the sandbox flags before the snippet code is actually injected into it (in `Snippet.writeResult()`, in the JS code you linked), and catching the submit event does that just fine.

Comment: This of course will only fix it for whoever installs it. How can we get SO to do this for real? It is weird to not be able to show a working snippet that uses alert from the OP's side (form validations for example)

Comment: @mplungjan: In principle, posting a bug report on Meta *is* the way to alert (pun not intended) SE to issues like this. Since this hasn't had any effect yet... well, you might try pinging an SE employee in chat (look for the ones who answer a lot of [meta-tag:bug] and [meta-tag:feature-request] posts), or perhaps (ab)using the [contact form](http://stackoverflow.com/contact). No guarantees on either of those, though.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Proper fix is in, will be live next time we build out. Thanks!

Comment: Form submits too please