# Alerts no longer work in Stack Overflow snippets in Chrome 46+

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome 46.0.2490.

JavaScript alerts within snippets do not work anymore at Stack Overflow. For example, this won't work in Chrome 46+:

```js
document.getElementById("alertButton").onclick = function() {
  alert("I won't alert!");
};
```

```html
<a href="#" id="alertButton">Click me!</a>
```

There is an error in a console:

> Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.

Currently, at Stack Overflow EN there are more than 500 000 answers which have modals in an answer. They all temporarily became non-working.

### Solution

The problem is that Stack Overflow defines snippet `iframe` as

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts"/>
```

However, in order to make it work, it needs to allow both scripts and modals:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-modals"/>
```

Additional information is available [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/block-modal-dialogs-sandboxed-iframe/).
Feature description at [Chrome Platform Status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4747009953103872).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297048/add-allow-modals-to-the-sandbox-of-stack-snippets-snippets-are-broken-in-chrome

Comment: @Cerbrus Oh, thanks. Sorry for a duplicate - still, there is no answer. The problem is becoming more serious now, after a stable release of Chrome 46.