# stacksnippets error?

Tags: bug

Below message intermittenly logged to `console` at SO , yesterday and today

```
Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-modals' is an invalid sandbox flag. jquery.min.js:4f.extend.clone 

jquery.min.js:4e.fn.e.init jquery.min.js:2e jquery.min.js:2i.generate snippet-javascript.en.js?v=efa2fd5b7d61:1(anonymous function) 

snippet-javascript.en.js?v=efa2fd5b7d61:1e.extend.each 

jquery.min.js:2e.fn.e.each jquery.min.js:2e.fn.snippet 

snippet-javascript.en.js?v=efa2fd5b7d61:1l snippet-javascript.en.js?v=efa2fd5b7d61:1(anonymous function) snippet-javascript.en.js?v=efa2fd5b7d61:1e.extend.each 

jquery.min.js:2e.fn.e.each 

jquery.min.js:2StackExchange.snippets.renderer.StackExchange.snippets.redraw.StackExchange.snippets.redraw snippet-javascript.en.js?v=efa2fd5b7d61:1(anonymous function) 

full.en.js?v=e4b372aa93ab:2b stub.en.js?v=95723302f031:1(anonymous function) 

full.en.js?v=e4b372aa93ab:2(anonymous function) full.en.js?v=e4b372aa93ab:6u wmd.en.js?v=4f03208bd3b8:3n 

jquery.min.js:2o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2w jquery.min.js:4d jquery.min.js:4
```

Comment: This is likely a result of the fix here: [Add allow-modals to the sandbox of Stack Snippets, snippets are broken in Chrome 46+](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297048/add-allow-modals-to-the-sandbox-of-stack-snippets-snippets-are-broken-in-chrome) It would likely help if you add what browser and version you are running to get the error.

Comment: At chromium browser version 37

Comment: That's probably [not an officially-supported version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). If you don't mind me asking, why are you on that old version?

Comment: @JeremyBanks _"That's probably not an officially-supported version."_ Interesting, was not aware of an official supported browsers list for stackexchange . The error was noticed yesterday , and continued today .

Comment: @JeremyBanks Note also, error appeared at `console` even while stacksnippets window was not open

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't think the developers are going to try to support a year-old version of Chrome, when more than 99.5% of Chrome users are on a more recent version.

Comment: @JeremyBanks _"I'm afraid that I don't think the developers are going to try to support a year-old version of Chrome"_ Yes , this is not expected result of Question . Error messages only began within past couple days ; no error prior to this , with `console` open throughout browsing session . Will try at chrome unstable to check if error logged there , when have opportunity

Comment: As mentioned in the linked question, Chrome 46 added the `allow-modals` option for the iframe sandbox attribute. This option did not exist in older versions of Chrome. For security reasons (presumably), if you specify a sandbox option that the browser can not provide, it raises an error.

Comment: @JeremyBanks No errors appear at chromium 49

Comment: In any case, the error appears to be harmless: testing on Chromium 45.0 shows that the iframe (and sandboxing) works just fine, with the unrecognized sandbox flag ignored as expected, despite the error messages logged to the console. It appears that, although this is reported by Chrome as an error, it is really just a harmless warning.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Should Question be deleted ?

Comment: @guest271314: I'd say probably not; someone else will just run into that error message and re-ask it. Better to have it here where it can be found. The devs will just mark it [meta-tag:status-declined] if they feel that it's not worth fixing.